# Java for loop with condition not incrementing

Tags: java, for-loop

This might be a silly question but I'm confused.

I have a for loop that excludes a given iteration (a random number). It works for any random number chosen that's greater than 0. However, if it's zero, it never does a single iteration:

```
int x;
for (x = 0; ((x < 2) && (x != r)); x++) {
    // do something if (x != r)

}
System.out.println("X : " + x);
```

For the example that it's not working, **r = 0**.
Shouldn't that mean it should skip the first iteration but does the second?

The above println yields "X : 0".

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: It never does a single iteration because you require `x != r` while your `x` is first set to 0, like your `r`, causing your condition to return `false` and not to enter the loop

Comment: Because of the condition(x < 2) && (x != r). As r =0, the condition fails and will not enter the loop.

Comment: No, the second expression is used as a way to end the loop.  If the expression evaluates to false, exit the loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Silly mistake! Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @tj56 When the first condition (second expression) becomes false, it exists the loop and continues execution after the loop.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to skip the first iteration, you must move the `x != r` condition inside the loop. Having the `x != r` condition in the loop's condition means the loop will never be entered if both `r` and `x` are initialized to `0`, since the loop terminates when the loop's condition becomes false.

```
for (x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    if (x != r) {
    // do something if (x != r)
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable r is chosen randomly so it might not be always the first iteration. But assuming it's always 0, why wouldn't it work the way I posted above?

Comment: @tj56 I added an explanation. If the loop's condition is false, the loop is terminated. If it's false before the first iteration, the loop is never entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (initialization; termination condition; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Above code will run:

```
    initialization
    termination condition
    statement
    increment

    termination condition
    statement
    increment

    termination condition
    statement
    increment

    ....
```

So you should remove condition `x != r` because before it runs statement for first time, it check that condition and return false.

You should note that. without condition `x != r`, your loop is run only twice: x = 0 and x = 1. Maybe in your code, those value (0 and 1) doesn't output any value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be great if you placed
(r >= 0) 
the random number generation would then be picked directly from 0.